Do these Raman scan output files really belong to the same exact Raman scan?
What I have got:

Two files from First Defender’s system named Scan227-dark.spc and Scan227.spc. Plain text versions of both files: plaintextOfScan227-darkspc.txt and plaintextOfScan227spc.txt.

Image file:


Scan227.txt exported from that First Defender.

Plotted graphs from both .spc files, named GraphOfScan227.oggu and GraphOfScan227dark.oggu – these have been created by my OriginPro, Version 2024 instance. Also exported these graphs to .png image files:




(Partially removed the “demo” words. I’ve got only evaluation license for OriginPro, planning to buy it…)

An image, exported from a slide of a ppt presentation:


(I removed non-English commentary from the slide.)
Notes:

The slide of the ppt presentation is not mine and currently I’m unable to contact the creator.
On the original ppt slide of BaselineCorrected1.png  if I double click those embedded pics containing the red label “- Session001:Scan227 – matched TATP (tr…”, following message pops up: “The server application, source file, or item can’t be found, or returned an unknown error. You may need to reinstall the server application.”
Opening with notepad the .spc files from the First Defender, you can read at the beginning: “Session001:Scan227 - matched TATP (triacetone triperoxide) (0.000000 single)?”
I’ve been told that the black lines on these graphs on ppt slides – if the picture is containing the label “- Session001:Scan227 – matched TATP (tr…” - are the baseline corrected version of the red one, but I couldn’t get any information about the applied method, function, or computational way of that baseline correction.
Here are my questions:


Is it possible anyway, that the plots on the GraphOfScan227dark.oggu
and GraphOfScan227.oggu correspond to the Session001-Scan227.jpg’s black line? I mean, if the actual scan is that black line, is it alright, that we see such (blue) graphs, after importing them to OriginPro, and making the plot? (For my eyes, they appear to be non-consistent in peak positions.)
If the first answer is yes, please describe to me, what is the computational relationship between them? How can I “infer” the blue graphs from that black plot in the jpg file, and vice versa (what is it? A baseline correction, peak fitting, signal processing or something like that?)? Or am I maybe completely misunderstanding the process, and overlooked a basic step?
Concerning the picture from ppt slide: can I assume, that the red line plots on the graphs labeled “- Session001:Scan227 – matched TATP (tr…”, are gained from the above provided .spc files or is it false? Are these graphs created by OriginPro? Finally: How could I reproduce them? I’ve got ready the above linked two .spc files: what kind of operation on these files would conclude to the same shape and sight of graph, what we see on BaselineCorrected1.png. My reason for that is that I’d like to do myself that baseline correction, depicted on those ppt slides.

Please, I’d highly appreciate any helpful answer and comment from You!
Thanks a lot, in advance.
Response to Jon Custer's comment:
They sent me multiple files, reportedly from the same Raman scan conducted with First Defender. My question is: if you consider the black line of the top picture, and  the blue “line” of the Scan227-dark graph; how is it possible, that these two graphs represent the same scan of the same material sample. And I doubt it, because of the obvious differences between these two plots. E. g. The top peak of the blue line at approximately 2500, where can You find that peak on the top pics black line, if they should be the plots of the same sample? Of course, maybe there is a standard operation I'm missing, but I tried many built in functions of OriginPro, and I never could convert the blue graph, to make it look even similar to the black graph. (Sorry if my language is confusing I hope I could clarify my doubts.)

Please use the built-in image uploader, not Google Drive links. Also, one question per post is optimal. Though I don't really see how this is a chemistry question, to begin with.

I've posted here because I was thinking this is analytical question related to Raman spectroscopy. Could You please advise me a more suitable place to this question?

There is a lot going on, and mostly in terms of software-related issues and data interpretation. That's not exactly chemistry, but I'm afraid on other SE sites the chance of getting a response will be even lower. You applied a lot of effort writing this question, so I'd leave it as is (just fix the images, please). But ideally you might want not the answer, rather a discussion on issues like this, and some forum, or Reddit would be better than a Q&A site (which Stack Exchange sites are) since there is very little room for back-and-forth discussion and one question per post is advisable.

Thank You for yout patience, and really , I worked hard on this question. I'd be glad with any answer which brings me closer to the final understanding of this. I can provide more information/detail if needed.

What is your question here? Is it whether or not the top picture, showing a match to a particular compound, is correct or not?

There are prominent features between $\pu{1000-1500 cm^-1}$in the blue trace that are missing in the black, suggesting these are not the same data, even if massaging (denoising) is considered. However these missing peaks might not be important to identify the compound of interest, for which the other signals might be the signatures of importance.
